# all .com.au websites not opening on my internet connection. I've static IP

Tags: dns, connection

I've internet connection with static IP. For some reason the websites with .com.au domain are not opening for me.

I checked by ping to those sites, it's not working. I checked with pin to IP address of those sites, it works out well. I checked with opening google.com.au, it's working.  I checked with different internet connection, it worked out. It is mostly not working with any other .com.au website.

Seems like my ISP settings or the domains has some setting that blocks my static IP to  access those sites.

Can anyone please help me on how to fix this issue.

Thanks, 
Raj

Comment: It got resolved after some time all of its own. It may be the issue with domain providers which marked my IP blocked for some time.

Answer (score 0):

I checked different websites to see what it could be. There were references to check my static IP in blacklist. It was all good over there. After some time it got resolved by it's own.

Thanks anyways.